# Merge data from a txt file with specific position and lenght for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Im trying to merge the content of a txt file with specific position and lenght for each column  with a table.

```
Example: From Position: 1  to Position: 7   = Col_1
         From Position: 8  to position: 21  = Col_2
         From Position: 22 to Position: 47  = Col_3
```

Im using `CAST(Substring(colum_Name,from_position, to_position) AS data_type) AS colum_name,`
to format this

In the Merge script, I all ready set the fixed lengh and position for each column.

And this is what im trying to do.

Create a table with just one column.

```
CREATE TABLE camposSinFormato(String VARCHAR(255)) 
GO
```

Then, BULK insert the content of the txt without format to that column.

```
BULK INSERT camposSinFormato
FROM 'F:\genera\completo\STK-TOTAL.TXT'
WITH(
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    );
GO
```

Now, i use merge to insert or update the table as needed.

My problem is that for doing so i have to use CAST(SUBSTRING to format the data before updating/inserting and i think im doing it wrong.

here is a sample of my merge code.

```
BEGIN TRAN;
    MERGE productos AS T
    USING camposSinFormato AS S
    ON (T.nroTroquel = S.nroTroquel) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
        THEN INSERT(
                    T.nroTroquel, 
                    T.nombre,
                    T.idlaboratorio,
                    T.precio, 
                    T.iva,
                    T.codigobarras,
                    T.tipoProducto,
                    T.subtipoProducto,
                    T.esRefrigerado
                    ) 
                VALUES 
                   (
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(S.String, 1, 7)AS BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY) AS nroTroquel,                     
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(S.String, 8, 21)AS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)AS nombre,                        
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(S.String, 22, 47)AS INT NOT NULL) as idlaboratorio,                       
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(S.String, 48, 62)AS MONEY NULL) as precio,                                
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(S.String, 63, 78)AS INT NULL) as iva,                                 
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(S.String, 79, 80)AS VARCHAR(13) NULL) as codigobarras,                
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(S.String, 81, 82)AS VARCHAR(14) NULL) as tipoProducto,                
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(S.String, 83, 84)AS VARCHAR(15) NULL) as subTipoProducto,             
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(S.String, 85, 91)AS BIT NULL) as esRefrigerado
                   )
        WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE 
                SET T.nombre = CAST(SUBSTRING(String, 8, 21)AS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)AS nombre,
                    T.idlaboratorio = CAST(SUBSTRING(String, 22, 47)AS INT NOT NULL) as idlaboratorio,
                    T.iva = CAST(SUBSTRING(String, 63, 78)AS INT NULL) as iva,  
                    T.codigobarras = CAST(SUBSTRING(String, 79, 80)AS VARCHAR(13) NULL) as codigobarras,
                    T.tipoProducto =  CAST(SUBSTRING(String, 81, 82)AS VARCHAR(14) NULL) as tipoProducto,
                    T.subtipoProducto = CAST(SUBSTRING(String, 83, 84)AS VARCHAR(15) NULL) as subTipoProducto,
                    T.esRefrigerado = CAST(SUBSTRING(String, 85, 91)AS BIT NULL) as esRefrigerado       

        WHERE S.nroTroquel = T.nroTroquel

    OUTPUT $action, updated, inserted.*;
```

Any one can tell me if the way im doing this is correct?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Sorry for the edit, i explained myself wrong in the original article

Comment: soooo many magic numbers

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say you were incorrect, but I think this process can be improved. If space is the delimiter, then change the BULK INSERT to specify FIELDTERMINATOR as a space. E.g.

```
BULK INSERT camposSinFormato
FROM 'F:\genera\completo\STK-TOTAL.TXT'
WITH(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    );
GO
```

You will need to define camposSinFormato correctly (i.e. instead of a single column, you will need to specify all columns).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Velonius. But i explained myself wrong.(all ready edited the article)
Im trying to merge the content of a txt file with specific position and lenght for each column with a table. 
Im using CAST(Substring(colum_Name,from_position, to_position) AS data_type) AS colum_name, to format this in the merg.